# Derivation of the Bayes' estimator with normal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, bayes-theorem

I'm currently studying about the Bayes' estimator using the book *Introduction to Machine Learning (Alpaydin, 2014)* and had a question regarding the calculations for the derivation. The specific part in the passage says:

> Let us suppose that $x^t \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, \sigma^2)$ and $\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma_0^2)$, where $\mu_0$, $\sigma_0^2$, and $\sigma^2$ are known:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> P(\mathcal{X} | \theta) & = \dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^{N / 2} \sigma^N}\text{exp} \left({-\frac{\sum_t (x^t - \theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) \\
> P(\theta) & = \dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2} \sigma_0} \text{exp} \left( -\frac{(\theta - \mu_0)^2}{2\sigma^2_0} \right)
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> It can be shown that $P(\theta | \mathcal{X})$ is normal with
>
> $$\mathrm{E}[\theta | \mathcal{X}] = \frac{N / \sigma^2}{N/\sigma^2 + 1/\sigma_0^2} m + \frac{1/\sigma_0^2}{N/\sigma^2 + 1/\sigma_0^2} \mu_0$$

The main parts that I'm having trouble understanding are 1) the calculation to get the conditional expectation shown above and 2) how this result means that $P(\theta | \mathcal{X})$ is normally distributed.

I am assuming that this has to do with the conjugate prior distribution as per [this community question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341625/bayes-estimator-of-normal-distribution-and-normal-prior) but is it enough to look at the form and observing that it is the conjugate prior, then conclude that the distribution of $\theta | \mathcal{X}$ is normal?

Regarding the calculation part, I attempted to calculate the equation by:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[\theta | \mathcal{X}] & = \int\theta P(\theta | \mathcal{X}) d\theta \\
& = \int \theta \dfrac{P(\mathcal{X} | \theta)P(\theta)}{P(\mathcal{X})} d\theta
\end{align}$$

and plugging in the appropriate PDF's into the equation. Is this approach correct?

Any tips or feedback are appreciated. Thanks in advance.